# Custom Post Limit for homepage only without plugin?

Tags: posts, customization, pagination, pre-get-posts, limit

I have a wordpress site where my most recent post is displayed on the home page larger than my other posts. Starting at post number 2, the posts are displayed in  a grid. I have pagination for 6 posts per page except for the first page, I need seven posts because of the fact that the most recent post is the largest and takes up two grid spaces. I am able to accomplish this with the plugin Custom Post Limits but I want to know if there is a way to do it without relying on a plugin. I have tried pre_get_posts, but don't know how to specify 7 posts on page 1 and 6 posts on every page after that.

I've tried something along these lines, but it doesn't work. Please help!

```
function custom_posts_per_page($query) {
    if ($query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query()) {
       $query->set('posts_per_page', '7');
       return;
    }

    if (!$query->is_home() && !$query->is_main_query()) {
       $query->set('posts_per_page', '6');
       return;
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_posts_per_page');
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take another approach. On home page, you have to make 2 queries:

one for latest post with parameters `post_per_page=1` to display the latest post;

and second query with parameters `post_per_page=6&offset=1` to display other posts (except latest) with pagination: 6 posts per page.